# Anyway to break this double-ended queue?

Tags: java

I have my own double ended queue implemented with a circular array such that the 'front' pointer points to the front element and the 'rear' pointer points to one element after the last element. At first they are both set to index 0.

```
Normal: 

    [X][X][ ][ ][ ]

     F     R  

Example: 

1.  [ ][ ][ ][ ][ ]

    FR  

2.  AddFirst 1 times

    [ ][ ][ ][ ][X]

     R           F

3.  Add 4 more times such that it's full

    [X][X][X][X][X]

    FR           

4.  RemoveFirst

    [ ][X][X][X][X]

     R  F
```

As you can see everything works just fine, but I'm thinking there is a way to break it. I'm saying this because if I implement F and R pointing to the first and last elements, doing what I did above WILL break it  i.e. R points to null which isn't true. So I'm wondering if it will ever happen in this implementation.

Assumptions: I have already implemented checks to prevent adding when full or removing when empty, adding and removing when capacity is zero, and adding null elements which in my implementation is disallowed.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Thanks for the info. I assume that full and empty cases will already be implemented. I will edit the post. But I don't know whether I have covered all cases.

Comment: So you have reinvented [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)… So why don’t you compare your implementation with Oracle’s and if you see differences try to find the reasoning behind them?